# PHP quiz with back and forward option

Tags: php

I want a PHP Quiz script which will having following features

1. User can select answer from multiple choices (radio button or checkboxes ) along with a small textarea for brief explanation where needed.
2. User can go back and forth to change any answer
3. Time will be on whole quiz not per question level
4. General Admin work of a quiz

I have searched but did not found a good solution for my need. Have anyone come across a matching PHP opensource script?

Comment: Q&D www.surveymonkey.com. I found a few but without what was rejected and reasons why then I've no idea what to suggest, other than that have fun writing it yourself.

Comment: www.surveymonkey.com is good. thanks

Comment: But it does not has marks attached to questions. It should calculate marks automatically and show result to user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen anything specifically like that, but you can adapt from `survey`, `voting`, or `ranking` scripts. Why not just write it yourself? seems like a pretty simple script to write up.

For example : http://sourceforge.net/projects/uccass/